# Real time request/response server (Java)

Tags: java, api, server, mocking

I need to write a service which will be acting as a real time mock server. We have multiple microservices and some of them are not ready. That is why I got a task to write this kind of service using java. But the main challenge for me is that it should create response upon requests in real time, so this service should mock APIs in real time without new deploy.

Architecture can be built on API calls which will set request and response, and those requests and responses will be used later.

Or it can read from some folder requests and responses in .json format files and mock APIs.

I am not sure did I explained my question clearly. Appreciate any kind of help.

I haven't tried something, but I saw [Mockoon](https://mockoon.com) has this functionality. It is written in python.

Comment: Yes, you can use Java REST API calls to connect to the server and then the front-end for passing the data. What have you attempted so far?

Comment: what do you mean? I think you misunderstood requirements

Comment: I would consider using wiremock for this purpose.
https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-wiremock

Answer (score -1):

Well, a simple mock server in your case can be build by -

1. Get the signatures & input/output payloads of your Microservices api's that are not yet developed. If the signatures & payloads are not yet defined, you need to get in a huddle with stakeholders to articulate them first
2. Simulate the input/output jsons and place them in a folder structure having the mapping in folder naming conventions
3. Write a simple Spring Boot Webservices component, with Swagger enabled. Your Spring endpoints can refer the json folders & return the example jsons. Swagger will allow you to publish an API listing url for consumption by respective teams.